# Reducing the amount of return statements (Python)

Tags: python, return, return-value

The function below returns the index within the list list_of_items of the first item that is equal to search_item. If no such items exist the function returns -1.

With a while loop rather than a for loop and not using any break statements nor index method of a list. How can I reduce my function below so that it only contains a single return statement?

Comment: Why can you not use any break statements? That's an awfully arbitrary limitation.

Comment: Is the "single return statement" thing a restriction you're given, or something you've decided is desirable? Under the other restrictions, I'd go with two return statements.

Comment: Also, `"-1"` is a very different thing from `-1`. `"-1"` is a string - it represents a minus sign and a 1 character, whereas `-1` would be an int, representing the integer directly below 0. You should almost certainly return `-1`, not `"-1"`.

Comment: These restrictions are given. I've managed to write my code with two return statements and I just can't get my mind around how can I reduce it down to only one return statement. Good point on the -1 (just realise that). @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: @Ava by reduce do you want shorter code ? or are you fine with more lines but just 1 return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the restriction to a `while` loop, and not using any `break` statements (making this seem a lot like a homework question), your best bet is to create a second condition that controls the execution of the loop. For example:

```py
def my_index(list_of_items, search_item):
    i = 0
    done = False
    return_value = '-1' # I suspect you meant this to be an int, not str

    while i < len(list_of_items) and not done:
        if list_of_items[i] == search_item:
            done = True
            return_value = i
        else:
            i += 1

    return return_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this considered breaking?

```
def my_index(list_of_items, search_item):
    res = -1
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_of_items):
        if list_of_items[i] == search_item:
            res = i
            i = len(list_of_items)
        else:
            i += 1
    return res
```

Comment: This breaks if `search_item` shows up at index 0 of `list_of_items`.

Comment: How about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_index(list_of_items, search_item):
    ret = -2
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_of_items):
        if list_of_items[i] == search_item:
            ret = i 
        elif i == (len(list_of_items) - 1):
            ret = -1
        if ret != -2:
            return ret
        i += 1

list_of_items = [3, 7, 2, 9, 11, 19]
print(my_index(list_of_items, 3))
```